# JOLT - How to transfer a list of elements to JSON

Tags: json, list, jolt

I have a list of elements and want to transfer it to JSON object

```
[12, 693, 9, 51]
```

Output result:

```
[
  {
    "customer_id": 12
  },
  {
    "customer_id": 693
  },
  {
    "customer_id": 9
  },
  {
    "customer_id": 51
  }
]
```

I tried the following spec but I get `null`.

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "customer_id": "[&1]"
    }
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

That will try to match on customer_id rather than generate it in the output. Try this one instead:

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": "[&0].customer_id"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you @mattyb!